# Does Terraform support Secondary CIDR for VPCs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to assign a secondary CIDR block to my VPC, but don't see how this is possible with terraform.

From the AWS docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html

> Adding IPv4 CIDR Blocks to a VPC
>
> You can associate secondary IPv4 CIDR blocks with your VPC. When you
>   associate a CIDR block with your VPC, a route is automatically added
>   to your VPC route tables to enable routing within the VPC (the
>   destination is the CIDR block and the target is local).

Does anyone know if this is supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the documentation around this [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/vpc_ipv4_cidr_block_association.html)

> When a VPC is created, a primary IPv4 CIDR block for the VPC must be specified. The *aws_vpc_ipv4_cidr_block_association* resource allows further IPv4 CIDR blocks to be added to the VPC

Answer (score 0):

As of mid 2023 this is definitely possible in the VPC module.

Per https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest

They actually give you an example at https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/tree/master/examples/secondary-cidr-blocks but in summary as an example you would use:

```
cidr                  = "10.0.224.0/20"
secondary_cidr_blocks = ["10.0.240.0/20"]
```

and then you would proceed to just use them:

```
private_subnets = [
  "10.0.224.0/23", "10.0.226.0/23", "10.0.228.0/23", # original vpc cidr w/ 512 ips each
  "10.0.240.0/22", "10.0.244.0/22", "10.0.248.0/22", # secondary cidr 1 w/ 1024 ips each
]
```

Additional settings you might care about so as to not incur additional nat gateway costs:

```
enable_nat_gateway     = true
one_nat_gateway_per_az = true
single_nat_gateway     = false
```

If you want to do it yourself with the aws provider I you would use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc_ipv4_cidr_block_association and then you would need to manage the subnets, route tables, etc. yourself. I've done it myself with cloudformation but don't have any terraform code handy to share.

Answer (score -1):

The [`aws_vpc` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/vpc.html) has an `assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block` parameter that is passable to it to allow for IPv6 CIDR ranges to be associated with the VPC which allows you to add an IPv6 range to your VPC but as of yet there's no support for adding an IPv4 range to the VPC.

You could raise a feature request for this on the [AWS provider's Github project](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/new).